# Is there a method to prevent values of previous runs stored in a txt file (prevent overwriting)?

Tags: c++, file-io

I am a beginner to C++ (doing file handling currently), I am facing a difficulty as my previous runs values are `overwritten`. I am looking for a remedy to this.

i want to save at least five inputs that may be added to my program ..... for eg name .. i ask for names.. and then store it

```
   .....
  ofstream f("f.txt");
  cin>>name
  f<<name;
   ....
```

what happens after each run is that the name entered in previous run gets overwritten ... is there ay way to prevent this?

Comment: Could you elaborate your question with pieces of code and a more explicit error description?

Comment: Edited and re-tagged to C++, this is not C.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might want to *append* to the file instead, see the [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ofstream/basic_ofstream):

```
 std::ofstream f( "f.txt", std::ios::app );
```

Comment: as i am new to file handling... can u provide a link for researching oon appending...will be very helpful of u

Comment: and consider another problem... i want to store only 10 program runs (  or append only 10 time) ... and start deleting the furthermore values...how do i do that?

Comment: Store that count in another file.

Answer (score 2):

You may also use `std::ios::ate` that cause all writing to added to end of file

```
std::ofstream f( "f.txt", std::ios::app | std::ios::ate )
```